# serve HTML5 mp4 video headers being cancelled

Tags: php, html, http-headers, jwplayer

I am trying to serve a video file. I got it working for the flash version however I want it to work on mobile devices using HTML5 video tag. I am using JWPlayer for the video player.

I saw [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices) solution from mobiforge.com and implemented it. Now it has helped me get it semi working and as it seems the correct headers are sent but not every page load, I have had to refresh it a couple times for the correct headers to appear. Also the request gets cancelled after downloading around 1.66MB of the video file.
then the video says the error.

```
The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or
because the format is not supported:
```